# Webhook disabled - how to restore it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got the following alert:

> Your Webhooks subscription for callback URL https://xxxxx has not been accepting updates for the past 483 minutes. We have disabled this subscription at this time. To reactivate the subscription, make a POST request with the same parameters, and it will be reactivated.

What POST request is it referring to?  And what same parameters?